# Image not showing up on canvas element

Tags: javascript, image, html, canvas, html5-canvas

So, I've been trying to make a scrolling shooter example with my game engine and I've come across something odd. A certain image I try to draw doesn't show up. It shows up in Chrome's resources, so it's not a path issue. Also all other images I try to display show up as well. If anyone can help me, it would be appreciated. =)

Link for reference:

http://pandamochi.x10.bz/scrollingshooter.html

Code for Drawing:

```
ctx.save();
        if (this.sprite != ""){
            ctx.translate(Math.round(this.x-ds_view.x), Math.round(this.y-ds_view.y));
            ctx.scale(this.scaleX,this.scaleY);
            ctx.rotate(this.rotateZ);
            ctx.translate(-this.width/2,-this.height/2);
            ctx.drawImage(this.sprite, this.width*this.sprite_index, 0, this.width, this.height, 0, 0, this.width, this.height);
        }
        ctx.restore();
```

Code I used to Set:

```
enemy.setSprite("images/ship.png",1,4,10);
```

Comment: Look in your Developer Console error log to see the error you are getting.

Comment: Try a different image so you can rule out a problem with the code. If another image works you know there's a problem with the image which you could try recreating / saving out again.

Comment: The image displays in chrome's resources though... And all other images I try work._.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**

So yeah I was way off.

```
ctx.drawImage(this.sprite, this.width*this.sprite_index, 0, this.width, this.height);
```

The translations are causing your issue. I changed the line above and can actually see the ship drawing. This isn't the most complete answer, but hopefully it gets you on the right track.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/Hq3vP/)**

Comment: are you sure? the image ship.png shows up perfectly in chrome's resources despite not showing up in the canvas...

Comment: @pandavenger no Im sorry I was way off. Check out my edited answer. Shameless plug, how I handle my drawing, https://github.com/loktar00/jest and a similar game http://somethinghitme.com/pprojects/shump/ using the engine.

Comment: oh I see... I must have been drawing someplace out of the actual image... I found a link that helped me out once you pointed out my problem. Thanks!

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Canvas_tutorial/Using_images

Comment: Hmm... so that's weird, I'm positive that my script is correct... Everything else shows up perfectly well... it's just that one image =(